# MongoDB date mismatch

Tags: mongodb

I have a .Net MVC app that, when submitted, captures the current DateTime in a jTable. The information in the jTable in populated from the MongoDB that the information hits when the app is submitted.

The problem I am having, is that when I go to export the data, it is showing the date -1 information for the current-day column. When I launch Studio 3T for MongoDB, the "DateCreated" column has date -1, but, when I hover the cursor over the row containing the "_id," it shows the correct, current date.

Is there a way to correct this that I am missing?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: 1. Have you tried viewing the data with a different tool, e.g. Robo3T, to see whether it is a problem with Studio 3T or a problem with your data?

Comment: 2. Is it possible that your application is saving the wrong date in the current-day field?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that your `date` field actually isn't a date field but a string field (you can see this by the type icon next to the value). It seems that in the export it gets converted to a simple string. I hope this helps!

(Disclaimer: I work for the company who makes Studio 3T)